# Express - Nodejs external rest api call

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make a backend call to an external api's and populate my page with the results. What is the best way to do this?

The "request.get" call is asynchronous, so I understand the code below is erroneous. However, I have written it in that fashion so that I can explain what I want to actually do.

Further, I may have 5-6 external api, is there a way to make this asynchronous for every api but synchronous get call?

This is how my current code looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var body = getRawApiResponse("someURL");
  console.log("Index >" + body);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', api: "some", body: body});

});


function getRawApiResponse(api){
  request.get({
    uri: api,
  },
  function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log("Index > Raw Api Response: " + body);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap getRawApiResponse() in a promise

```
function getRawApiResponse(api){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request.get({
      uri: api,
    },
    function(error, response, body){
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          resolve(body)
        } else {
          reject(error)
        }
      });
  });
}
```

which resolves on success and rejects in case of an error then you can chain it inside the get request like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getRawApiResponse("someURL")
          .then(function(body){
              res.render('index', { title: 'Express', api: "some", body: body});
          })
          .catch(err){
              // do something
          }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into Promises or async/await. You can use them to call your async apis and wait for the response making the call synchronous.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

A Sample code of async/ await which u can modify for ur purpose is as below:

```
try{
                let orderDetails = await MongoHelper.findOneByCriteria(MongoCollections.ORDER,searchCriteria);
        }catch(err){
                 return err;
        }


  MongoHelper.findOneByCriteria = (collectionName, criteria) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection(collectionName).find(criteria).toArray()
            .then((results) => {
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    resolve(results[0]);
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Promises to avoid callbacks hell. If you can use node.js v7.6 or higher, it could be much easier with async/await.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getRawApiResponse("someURL")
    .then(body => {
      console.log("Index >" + body);
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express', api: "some", body: body});
    });
});

function getRawApiResponse(uri) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get({ uri }, (error, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}
```

In the example about I use *promisification* to return a promise from `getRawApiResponse`, but there is already a module which do the same https://github.com/request/request-promise.